# Как использовать метод dataset в jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery

У меня возник вопрос, как я могу удалить блоки через dataset. Чтобы каждый блок удалялся по отдельности по клику. У меня происходит немного иначе. Первый блок удаляется нажатие на кнопку, а вот второй нет. Все два блока удаляются.Подскажите пожалуйста

```js
$('.remove').on('click', function() {
  $('[data-product-id="1"]').remove();
  $('[data-product-id="2"]').remove();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cart" data-product-id="1">
  <span class="remove"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-ban"></i></a></span>
</div>

<div class="cart" data-product-id="2">
  <span class="remove"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-ban"></i></a></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $('.remove').on('click', function () {
    $(this).remove(); 
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart" data-product-id="1">
  <span class="remove">
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-ban">Удалить только 1</i></a>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="cart" data-product-id="2">
  <span class="remove">
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-ban">Удалить только 2</i></a>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="cart" data-product-id="3">
  <span class="remove">
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-ban">Удалить только 3</i></a>
  </span>
</div>
```

как видите для удаления не требуется **data-product-id**

Comment: Тогда удаляться все элементы, а мне надо выборочно

Comment: @КириллМитин, удалится тот элемент на который нажали

Answer (score 0):

Осмелюсь предположить, что при нажатии на `.remove`, вам нужно удалить `.cart`, в котором находится тот самый `.remove`.
Если да, то для этого не обязательно иметь какой-то `data` атрибут, достаточно наследия.

```js
$('.remove').on('click', function() {
  let parent = $(this).closest('.cart')
  parent.remove();
  console.info(parent.data('product-id'));
});
```

```css
.cart {
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cart" data-product-id="1">
  <span class="remove"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-ban"></i></a></span>
</div>

<div class="cart" data-product-id="2">
  <span class="remove"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-ban"></i></a></span>
</div>
```